# why of 2 identical micro-controllers, only one can connect to a given device?

Tags: bluetooth, windows

I am working with 2 identical (Arduino) [Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2995)s. Only one of them can connect to a Universal Windows Platform [app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE) running on a  Windows 10 machine. The other connection fails with [Unreachable](http://GattCommunicationStatus) status.

I am only trying to connect with one MCU at one time. Both MCUs are loaded with the same program which resets the Bluetooth Unit. Both MCUs can connect to an Android app. Neither board appear damaged.

Why could a UWP app be able to connect to one board but not another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than a software issue, there is no reason it shouldn't work. Only thing may be identical Bluetooth names or ids. Clear the device from windows and try again.

I have some cheap Bluetooth obd 2 readers that all use the same Bluetooth mac address and name. I have to delete one from my android phone before adding the new one to connect to it.

Comment: They have different addresses but the same name. The one that couldn't connect was paired (through the os) to the computer. It could connect after unpairing. I experimented by pairing the other. It could no longer connect if the other had been connected.

Comment: Yep, and that's because sometimes the app or system looks for the name and sometimes the Mac address and sometimes both. Unique everything solves that. Same thing with a pair of cheap bluetooth speakers. Change the name and it starts working.